# Unpublished internal link still generates a 200 OK and View not found message

Tags: menu-item, seo

I am facing a really weird issue and can't figure out what is going on here. An internal menu item (added by clicking 'Article') was unpublished and I was expecting the 404 to be generated. But when I click in the in page link, it is generating the following URL structure (which I suppose is the Joomla router trying to create an URL)

```
/component/content/11-new-books/sci-fi/137-foundation-and-empire?Itemid=31
```

And the HTML content of the page displayed is as the follows.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
   <body>View not found [name, type, prefix]: 11new-books, html, contentView</body>
</html>
```

What could be happening here for it to not even display the error page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try clicking "Rebuild" in menu manager. The sef router is not kept up-to-date automatically, after making changes to the menus you may need to "rebuild" the relevant data.

The reason 404 is not generated is that the link is routed to com_content or content manager, that is what happens by default if a menu item for neither article or category is found. Since the link is broken this fails, but Joomla! gives a fail notice instead of a server error for the very simple reason that it has no way to know which error would be the correct one. If a route fails, it has failed.

Mostly guesswork, obviously.

Comment: Thanks for that. Will give it a go and let you know the outcome.